# prolog fact lexical analyser in python

Tags: python, prolog, lexical-analysis

I am interested in being able to read and manipulate prolog 'facts' using python

To facilitate this, how might one write a lexical analyser in python that could read a set of facts from a text file?

a set of facts might look something like:

```
track(1, 2.0, 4000, 3, 300).
track(2, 1.0, 9000, 5, 500).
track(3, 7.0, 9000, 2, 200).
...
```

Comment: Will every line have the exact same format as the lines you just posted (As in, do you need to be able to parse any arbitrary prolog fact, or just a subset similar to the ones you've just posted)? If so then it's probably best to just hand tool a parser.

Comment: ideally any arbitrary prolog fact

Comment: I'd rather go with a clean subset to parse. If you want to parse "any arbitrary Prolog fact" you will need a general Prolog parser. And that's a rather ambitious project. Here are [testcases for it](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_assessment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use the [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/HowToUsePyparsing) module for creating parsers of this nature in python. Pyparsing is a parser combinator library; you construct the parser by combining together other parsers. Here's an example parser using pyparsing that will parse your input data (it won't be able to parse any prolog fact, but I think it will be a nice starting point):

```
import pyparsing as pp
#relationship will refer to 'track' in all of your examples
relationship = pp.Word(pp.alphas).setResultsName('relationship')

number = pp.Word(pp.nums + '.')
variable = pp.Word(pp.alphas)
# an argument to a relationship can be either a number or a variable
argument = number | variable

# arguments are a delimited list of 'argument' surrounded by parenthesis
arguments= (pp.Suppress('(') + pp.delimitedList(argument) +
            pp.Suppress(')')).setResultsName('arguments')

# a fact is composed of a relationship and it's arguments 
# (I'm aware it's actually more complicated than this
# it's just a simplifying assumption)
fact = (relationship + arguments).setResultsName('facts', listAllMatches=True)

# a sentence is a fact plus a period
sentence = fact + pp.Suppress('.')

# self explanatory
prolog_sentences = pp.OneOrMore(sentence)
```

Now we have a parser for your input in the `prolog_sentences` variable. Here's a test of the parser:

```
test="""track(1, 2.0, 4000, 3, 300).
track(2, 1.0, 9000, 5, 500).
track(3, 7.0, 9000, 2, 200)."""

result = prolog_sentences.parseString(test)

print result['facts'][0]['arguments'].asList()
# outputs ['1', '2.0', '4000', '3', '300']

print result['facts'][1]['relationship']
# outputs 'track'

print result['facts'][2]['arguments'][1]
# outputs ['7.0']
```

Comment: I would say PLY is fantastic if you're already familiar with lex/yacc parsing. One thing that I like about pyparsing over lex/yacc is that once I've constructed my grammar, I can come back to it 6 months later and be able to understand what I wrote very quickly. Pyparsing sacrifices brevity (and probably performance) for readability when compared to PLY.